# Class not found error with composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, zoho

I must be making a simple error, I have not used Composer before now. I have followed the instructions on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk), but I'm getting a `Class 'ZCRMRestClient' not found` error when I load the page.

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "zohocrm/php-sdk": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

PHP is

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$configuration = array(
    'client_id' => '1000.***',
    'client_secret' => '***',
    'redirect_uri' => '***',
    'currentUserEmail' => '***',
);

ZCRMRestClient::initialize($configuration);

$contacts = ZCRMRestClient::getModule(“Contacts”);

echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($contacts);
echo "\n</pre>";
```

I've tried `\ZCRMRestClient::initialize($configuration)` but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you try `\zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient`? The class is in that namespace, so you'll either need to use the FQCN every time, or add a `use` statement to your script.

Comment: Where is the full path (namespace) if u add use syntax for zcrmresrclient execute with successful

Comment: Just put `use zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient` at the top of your script to use that class from autoloader

Comment: Both Maerlyn and weegee told you how to fix this. Have you used their advise?

Comment: No, I'm not sure it's the right solution, because I'm going to need to do that for every class I use and they're all buried deep.

Comment: That's how you use the autoloader. You have a thing called [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php), I recommend you do read about [how composer works](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#dependency-management) and how autoloading works, [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Comment: That's exactly the solution. There is no other way of using autoloading.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've executed the `composer require zohocrm/php-sdk` command, or potentially added the requirement straight into your project's composer.json by hand.

Make sure you're importing the correct namespace for the library - in this case it seems to be `zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient`

You should write `use zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient;` at the top of the file then invoke methods as you currently do.

Alternatively, you can invoke methods as in the following example: `\zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient::initialize($configuration);`

After that the most likely problem is that your autoload file doesn't contain a reference to your library.

`composer dump-autoload` should fix that (from the command line.)

And finally perhaps you are not requiring the vendor folder correctly!

Comment: did `composer dump-autoload` gave `Generated autoload files containing 0 classes`

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the details of your composer.json file. Are you sure you've run the ```composer require...``` command?

Comment: Will do. Yes, I did `composer require zohocrm/php-sdk` which seemed to run fine. Will update question with json.

Answer (score 1):

There is new sdk 3.0 available, and the old sdk 2.0 is moved to:

```
"require": {
    "zohocrm/php-sdk-archive": "^2.0"
}
```